# Cannot find DBT container ID in Docker Container

Tags: docker, airflow, dbt, astronomer

I am just learning DBT integration with Apache Airflow and in that process i was following this tutorial to setup a simple working demo. [Tutorial link](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-dbt)

Now i am able to run the sample dbt job as per this article, but if i want to go steps further i am required to run DBT commands such as dbt debug, dbt run etc. for that to happen i need to find DBT container ID to pass these commands to dbt container CLI.

Below is the output of all the container it list as running.

```
docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      NAMES
4e0086544   mds-warehouse_2329c1/airflow:latest        mds-warehouse_2329c1-webserver-1
a51162f51   mds-warehouse_2329c1/airflow:latest        mds-warehouse_2329c1-scheduler-1
08071f433   mds-warehouse_2329c1/airflow:latest        mds-warehouse_2329c1-triggerer-1
89f564020   postgres:12.6                              mds-warehouse_2329c1-postgres-1
c0cce02b2   airbyte/proxy:0.50.39                      airbyte-proxy
82b9705b9   airbyte/server:0.50.39                     airbyte-server
409993ab2   airbyte/worker:0.50.39                     airbyte-worker
f7aef5e4f   airbyte/cron:0.50.39                       airbyte-cron
48b13d180   airbyte/connector-builder-server:0.50.39   airbyte-connector-builder-server
5a3c41a24   airbyte/airbyte-api-server:0.50.39         airbyte-api-server
c091d4be9   airbyte/webapp:0.50.39                     airbyte-webapp
70841df8d   airbyte/bootloader:0.50.39                 airbyte-bootloader
0c524886e   airbyte/temporal:0.50.39                   airbyte-temporal
25543187c   airbyte/init:0.50.39                       init
433d07efa   airbyte/db:0.50.39                         airbyte-db
```

Now, how do i run dbt commands, if i cannot find its container ID. the above is the list Docker shows for all the containers running (also running airbyte, so it shows several airbyte lines)

Comment: As soon as the DBT job finishes, the container will shut down. If the goal is to run dbt commands for development (i.e. `dbt debug`), one of the options listed in dbt's documentation (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/installation-overview#install-dbt-core) can be used to install DBT.  Note that depending on the installation method, slight adjustments in the configuration might be needed.

Comment: this is from my dockerfile , it does install dbt-postgres-- >> FROM quay.io/astronomer/astro-runtime:10.0.0

# replace dbt-postgres with another supported adapter if you're using a different warehouse type
RUN python -m venv dbt_venv && source dbt_venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir dbt-postgres && deactivate